# When using an insert into statement in SQL, what element is put in place of the value for an auto increment field

Tags: sql

I have created 2 tables both linked with a (pID) as the primary and foreign key. The pID is an (auto increment field) primary key in the painters table and the foreign in the painter_specs table. How do i auto fill the pID field in the painter_specs to the corresponding pID field in the painters table (which is auto incremented)?

Here is my code

```
CREATE TABLE painters (
pID     INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
First_Name  CHAR(45) NOT NULL,
Last_Name   CHAR(45) NOT NULL,
Address     CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
primary key (pID));

INSERT INTO painters VALUE (NULL, 'John', 'Doe', '123 Markt St Manassas VA     20021');
INSERT INTO painters VALUE (NULL, 'Jane', 'Smith', '342 Water St.    Centreville VA 20121');
INSERT INTO painters VALUE (NULL, 'Mike', 'Williams', '390 Bank Ave Fairfax     VA 20201');

CREATE TABLE painter_specs (
pID     FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES painters(pID);
Title   CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Date    DATE NOT NULL,
Painter CHAR(90) NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO painter_specs VALUE(NULL, 'Morning Mist', '10/10/2015',     'Beautiful painting about mist', 'John Doe');
INSERT INTO painter_specs VALUE(NULL, 'Evening Shadows', '10/12/2015', 'Beautiful painting about shadows', 'John Doe');
INSERT INTO painter_specs VALUE(NULL, 'Afternoon Thoughts', '10/11/2015', 'Beautiful painting about memories', 'Jane Smith');
```

Using the insert into statement, I currently have NULL in place of the value to be auto populated in the painter_specs table by the painters table.

Comment: The answer is probably going to be programming-language specific, as different sql libraries have their own way to retrieve the primary key of inserted rows. Also, it would be helpful to mention which database you are using.

Comment: Are you using MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert values into the `painters` table, use the following:

```
INSERT INTO painters (First_Name,Last_Name, Address) VALUES
('John', 'Doe', '123 Markt St Manassas VA     20021'),
( 'Jane', 'Smith', '342 Water St.    Centreville VA 20121'),
('Mike', 'Williams', '390 Bank Ave Fairfax     VA 20201');
```

Once you the database populates the `pID` column in the `painters` table, replace the `[pID]` in the insert statements for the `painter_specs` table below with the `pID` the row references as part of the `FOREIGN KEY` - e.g `1, 2, 3, etc.`

```
INSERT INTO painter_specs (pID, Title, Date, Painter) VALUES 
([pID], 'Morning Mist', '10/10/2015',     'Beautiful painting about mist', 'John Doe'),
([pID], 'Evening Shadows', '10/12/2015', 'Beautiful painting about shadows', 'John Doe'),
([pID], 'Afternoon Thoughts', '10/11/2015', 'Beautiful painting about memories', 'Jane Smith');
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thank You

Comment: Based on my INSERT INTO painters statement,  i seem to get an error message stating "the column count does not match the value count." I assume it's because the painters table has 4 required fields and i am attempting to insert only 3 values.

Comment: i had to make additional changes to some more code, but it did work. Thanks